# Не выводится alert, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу сделать оповещение при сохранении данных
В контроллере `return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('success', 'Настройки успешно сохранены!');`
Создал flash-message.blade.php, там указал [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге вместо оповещения расширяется пространство перед div'ом с настройками [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прогуглил всё, но не смог найти, надеюсь тут мне помогут)

Comment: В документации нет примеров с переменной в @if структуре (https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#control-structures). Используйте без неё Session::has и Session::get

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)

Comment: В таком случае пометьте мой ответ как подходящий, и успехов с нашем сообществе!

Answer (score 3):

В документации нет примеров с переменной в @if структуре (https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#control-structures). Используйте без неё Session::has и Session::get